# Running all Tests in Production Template in Shopware 6.3.5.2

Tags: testing, phpunit, tdd, cypress, shopware

We are building a shop for a customer on Shopware 6.3.5.2 and want to use tests to

- ensure that core functionality is not broken by our customizations (static plugins)
- write new tests for new functionality

There is [Running End-to-End Tests](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/testing/end-to-end-testing/running-e2e-tests) but this seems to be for core development and uses `psh.phar` which is not available in the production template.

How should this be done?

*edit*
This question is meant a bit broader and concerns also Unit Tests.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use the E2E tests of the platform project - as Cypress itself doesn't care where to run the test against. However, as you already noticed you cannot use `psh` commands to run them. You may run the tests though the basic Cypress commands, setting your shop's url as `baseUrl` of the tests, for example via this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config baseUrl="<your-url>"
```

It works with `cypress open` as well.

The only thing what may become troublesome is the `setToInitialState` command in most of the tests which takes care about the clean up of shopware's database using `psh` scripts, unfortunately. You may need to adjust it by overriding the command in order to reset the database of the `Production` template.

I hope I was able to help a bit.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't even have `node_modules/.bin/cypress` because https://github.com/shopware/production does not have a packages.json - and after npm `install cypress` it's missing the cypress config file.

Comment: okay, like this it starts up the tests
`vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/test/e2e$ npm install`
`vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/test/e2e$ node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config baseUrl="http://...."`

Comment: Next it tries to access `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8005` to to some cleanup, which is not working

Comment: Yes As said, the cleanup method might fail, being tailored specifically for `development` template. Unfortunately, there's no support in `Production` yet, so we need to override the corresponding command: In there, the command `cleanUpPreviousState` will break, see [here](https://github.com/shopware/e2e-testsuite-platform/blob/37df739e7216b4b4500edd5dc502ccfd84151771/cypress/support/commands/system-commands.js#L33). So please override `setToInitialState` to use your own cleanup method by copying it in your local `support` folder - so that `cleanUpPreviousState` wont be executed.

Comment: Concerning cleanup: At Shopware, a mysqldump is used to reset the database. If you want to do that as well, you just need to make cypress communicate with your database, e.g. by using scripts via `cy.exec`. However, please feel free to try out other cleanup methods, matching your needs. 

Comment: Thanks once again - I am wondering if we are using the wrong approach of if nobody else uses tests with production template for customer shops?

Comment: This is actually a well-discussed topic in general.  Testing on production systems has pro's and con's. I myself prefer testing in dev environment most of the time. However, I can understand that you want to be as close on the customer's perspective as possible. Especially with Dockware it might be a good idea at least to create content on that.  What are your thoughts on testing in production?

Comment: We don't want to test on production servers, but a shop created with the production template, which we believe is the correct way when creating a "full" shopware instance and not some general purpose plugins for the marketplace. Or is this the wrong approach in general?

Comment: I wouldn't call it wrong, it's like a staging system I suppose. I cannot promise as I'm here as a private person, but I'll see if I can create some content or even a script helping in that. A good opportunity to learn more about the `Production` template I think. At least I want to forward your feedback, it's really appreciated. ❤️

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I'll post here as soon as there are any news.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two parts here:

1. ensure that core functionality is not broken by our customizations (static plugins)
2. write new tests for new functionality

re 1: For regression tests like this I would suggest end-to-end tests. Either test through the UI with tools like selenium or through the HTTP API (I don't know if the shopware API is sufficient for extensive regression tests).

re 2: Since plugins do not run on their own I would extract all relevant functionality into plain old PHP classes that are independent of shopware and test those in isolation. Explore if some of that functionality can be made visible through an API and test the plugin integration through this. Depending on the actual plugin you might have to resort to UI tests again.

Comment: I was hoping I can use the existing cypress tests for 1.